# Effective Dart Usage: decleare variables with same value and same type

Tags: dart

How could I make the following code shorter?:

```
String foo = "same";
String foo1 = "same";
```

One approach I guess would be:

```
String foo = "same", foo1 = "same";
```

However I don't find this satisfactory as the values I give to both variables are the same.

I'm looking for something like (pseudo code):

```
String foo & foo1 = "same";
```

so that both foo and foo1 are of type String and both have the same value.

Comment: If you want to avoid repeating the *value*, you can do: `String foo, foo1; foo = foo1 = "same";`. That requires repeating the names, though. There is not way to declare two values *and* initialize them both with only one initializer expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
void main() {
  String foo = 'same', bar = foo;

  print(foo); // same
  print(bar); // same
}
```

I would say that the readability is not that great here and I personally would prefer to just declare each variable with the value it should have. Or do something like this:

```
void main() {
  String foo = 'same';
  String bar = foo;

  print(foo); // same
  print(bar); // same
}
```

Again, short code is not necessary readable code. Sometimes, it is better to make it clear what happens even if it takes more lines to do it. :)